# Condition for existance of a triangle with vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

Let$\ \vec a, \vec b, \vec c \ $  be noncollinear vectors. Show that the necesssary and sufficient condition for the existence of a triangle $ABC$ with the properties
$\vec {BC}=\vec a ,\vec {CA}= \vec b , \vec {AB}=\vec c \ \ $is$ \ \vec a × \vec b =
\vec b ×
\vec c =
\vec
c ×
\vec 
a $.
From the equalities of the norms deduce the law of sines.

Can somebody give me some tips, please? I don't know what condition for existance of a triangle to use.

Answer (score 1):

$$\vec{BC}+\vec{CA}+\vec{AB}=\vec{BB}=0$$
You can write this as $$\vec a+\vec b+\vec c=0$$
Now multiply this equation by $\vec c$ (vector product, not scalar)
$$\vec a\times\vec c+\vec b\times\vec c+\vec c\times\vec c=0$$
Use properties of the vector product.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to do it this way. But is this an if and only if relation, or just the implication from left to right?

Comment: This is just from left to right, but you can repeat the steps backward.

Comment: The only step that is somehow more problematic to justify is that if $(\vec a+\vec b+\vec c)\times \vec v=0$ then $\vec a+\vec b+\vec c=0$, where $\vec v$ is each one of $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c$

Comment: Can you advice me about how that can be proven, please?

Comment: Since $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are non collinear, you can use two directions that are perpendicular $\hat a_{||}$ and $\hat a_\perp$, first parallel to $\vec a$, then the second perpendicular, towards $\vec b$ Use Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization. Then let $\vec d=\vec a+\vec b+\vec c$. Write the components along the two perpendicular directions. You should get that both components are $0$.

Comment: Also, just in case you are doing 3D geometry, from the equality of the three cross products you can get that $\vec c $ is in the plane formed by the other two vectors. Once again, decompose $\vec c$ in a component in the $ab$ plane, and a component perpendicular to it$